# Getting archive notification from Gmail while nothing was done

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail-api

I have an app linked to Gmail using the Gmail API (with Node/Javascript).

Everything works fine except that I sometimes get a notification (history) saying that the INBOX label was removed from a message (or a couple of messages).

I'm positive that no action was performed on the Gmail account.
I also made sure that:

1. There is no "Skip Inbox" filter set which is catching more mail than it should.
2. There is no forwarding set up from this account to another account.
3. There is no other account that is fetching mail from this one, so no "archive Gmail's copy" and no "Mailfetcher to archive the incoming mail from that source".
4. There is no "unified Inbox" in one of our other access clients/devices, which removes messages from the Gmail Inbox and leaves them only visible in All Mail.
5. I'm not using the Move label feature.

And finally I made sure that no access is performed to the Gmail account from any other 3rd-party app (Mail on iPhone for example). All access were revoked.

I'm not sure if this is due to the Gmail API or if it's a bug on Gmail side.
Quite hard to compare with the Gmail interface as we need to click on the refresh button to see if something happened.

Any idea of what could be triggering that notification?

Thanks,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your [`watch` requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#watch_request).

If there's an error from the `watch` call, this is typically with the setup of the Cloud Pub/Sub topic and subscription. As suggested in the documentation, refer to the [Cloud Pub/Sub documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) to confirm that the setup is correct and for help with debugging topic and subscription issues.

In addition to that, please check [Subscriber Overview](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber) for more information.

Comment: Hi, I don't think my issue is related to the `watch`. I perform a single `watch` call to create the subscription and then everything works fine.

It's just that sometimes I receive an update on a message saying that the `INBOX` label was removed while no action was performed on Gmail.